# Storing payment info

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, payment-gateway, payment

This is more of a general question regarding the storage and retrieval of payment information for web commerce applications

Our current approach is to have the user enter their payment details after a redirect on a 3rd party web form, similar to what one might do with PayPal.

In order to make it easier for repeat orders, obviously involves storing payment information details, such as credit card numbers, PII information.

Since this has serious security implications, I am wondering what the general accepted best practices are.  Is it basically recommended to handle all of this with other tools such as Stripe?  Or have others gone with in-house solution ?

For reference, we are working with Java Servlets/JSP.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer for this question is **NO**, don't store anything. Let's 3rd party payment gateway like Paypal do it for you.

It's not only about security (which you will likely do wrong), it also has to deal with regulations, such as the right to store sensitive data such as credit card.

An alternative, very-risky-and-should-be-avoided answer is to store it in browser's session storage. As for this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36958/is-it-safe-to-store-password-in-html5-sessionstorage), session storage is reasonably secure. Remember to use HTTPS and have XSS prevention in place. But again, this is not recommended by me.

Comment: It got downvoted because it';s too broad and not a specific programming question

Comment: Thanks haipham.  I think you got the point and answered perfectly, not sure what john is trying to say.  But after reading the answers here it does seem a better option to go with other tools that handle the PCI compliance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather wide-ranging, and "best practice" is often another word for personal preference and prejudice.

However...

In most countries, to process credit card details requires you to have an arrangement with your bank (often called "cardholder not present"), and the bank will impose fairly strict security requirements on you when you take up that arrangement. In the UK, these requirements are known as "Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS)".

There are varying options here - a large online store may invest in storing payment details on their infrastructure, but the cost for meeting the required security standards is significant.

You can also work through a [payment gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_payment_service_providers) - an intermediary company which manages the interaction with the banks. They usually have several different integration options - from "Paypal-like" redirects to an API which allows you to collect the credit card data, and pass that through an API to verify payment. Many payment gateways allow you to store the payment details on their infrastructure (which is PCI compliant), and retrieve a token for future payments.

The process is something like:

```
customer places first order
customer enters payment details
payment gateway verifies payment details
payment gateway collects payment
payment gateway stores payment details
payment gateway sends token to website
website stores payment token with customer profile
customer places second order
website retrieves payment token
website asks "use previous payment details"
customer agrees
website sends token to payment gateway
payment gateway retrieves payment details
payment gateway collects payment
payment gateway tells website payment succeeded
```

Comment: Thanks Neville, since we are looking for a way to let customers who have purchase before easily repurchase, we would like to avoid them needing to re enter the payment information every time.  Sounds like too much of a hassle to store the information ourselves